# Why tailwind does not work when I run npm run start, but it works when I run ng serve

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I have an angular 15 app with tailwind.

Proxy.conf.json:

```
{
    "/api/": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": false
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development"
  },
...
```

When I run `ng serve` the app and tailwind design works but because of the missing proxy I can not communicate with the backend.

When I run `npm run start`, proxy works, but the tailwind does not. It's only showing default html.
What could be the problem?

I work on Linux machine, I tried it with my friends laptop which runs Windows and it worked there.

Comment: Did u check whether the versions are the same? Check ur global and local Angular Versions.

Comment: I had Local 15.0.5 and global 15.0.1. Updated both to 15.1.3 and now it works! Thx!

Comment: Thats nice! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

So the solution was to match the global and local versions of angular/cli.

From
Local: 15.0.5
Global: 15.0.1

To
15.1.3

Explanation:
When I run ng serve I use the global installed angular-cli and when I run npm start i use the local one. So this specific version mismatch caused the problem.